# How to organize a two-way communication with the Firefox extension code injection?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, code-injection, dom-events

There is an extension for Firefox, which makes the injected JS code into the page.

Code for XUL:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
document.addEventListener("TestEvnt", function (e) {
    var info = e.detail;
    if(info.cmd=='account_list') {
        consoleLog('... event account_list');
    }
}, false, true);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
  var window = e.originalTarget.defaultView.wrappedJSObject;
  var inject = window.document.createElement('script');
  inject.type = 'text/javascript';
  inject.setAttribute('src','resource://apptab-notify/injscr.js');
  window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(inject);
}, false);
},false);
```

Code injscr.js:

```
var additionalInfo = {
        "cmd": 'account_list',
        "url": document.location.href
    };
var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
evt.initCustomEvent('TestEvnt', true, false, additionalInfo);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

How to provide bi-directional communication, something to listen to code injection events from the extension? Without using Addon-SDK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In injsrc.js:

```
var additionalInfo = {
    "cmd": 'account_list',
    "url": document.location.href
};

var request = document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(additionalInfo));
request.addEventListener("something-response", function(event) {
    console.log('... something-response');
    var info=JSON.parse(event.target.nodeValue);
    $('body').css('background-color', info.color);
}, false);
document.head.appendChild(request);
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("something-query", true, false);
request.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In XUL:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
   document.addEventListener("something-query", function(event) {
        consoleLog('... something-query');
        var node = event.target;
        if (!node || node.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) return;
        var info = JSON.parse(node.nodeValue);
        var doc = node.ownerDocument;

        if (info.cmd == 'account_list') {
            consoleLog('... event account_list');
            var event = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent("something-response", true, false);
            node.nodeValue = JSON.stringify({
                'color': '#999'
            });
            node.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else if (info.cmd == 'page_options') {
            consoleLog('page_options');
        }
    }, false, true);
}, false);
```

Article helped [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages#Chromium-like_messaging.3A_json_request_with_json_callback)

Comment: Surely there is a better way then inserting #text nodes into the head? What if the messages being passed were sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the communication from content to chrome working correctly already, why not use the same approach in the reverse direction as well? Meaning that in `injscr.js` you would register an event handler:

```
window.addEventListener("TestEvnt2", function(event)
{
  var info = event.detail;
  ...
}, false);
```

And in your chrome code you would generate an event:

```
var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
event.initCustomEvent("TextEvnt2", false, false, additionalInfo);
gBrowser.contentWindow.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This dispatches the event to the `window` object of the current tab but you could just as well go through all the tabs and dispatch the event to all of them (depends on what you are trying to do).

Comment: Such an option has already tried it (of course my code is a bit different). The result is that my that your - does not fire event, without any error message.